# Java 8 Optional filter only if present

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have a nullable object and I'm trying to throw an exception if the object is not `null` and does not meet a condition.

I try this way with `Optional`:

```java
Optional.ofNullable(nullableObject)
    .filter(object -> "A".equals(object.getStatus()))
    .orElseThrow(() -> new BusinessUncheckedException("exception message"));
```

When the object is not `null`, it works as I want, but otherwise, it throws the exception too (and I don't want that).

There is a way to do that with `Optional` or other ways not using `if object != null`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you aren't doing anything with the returned object, you could use `ifPresent` and pass a `Consumer`

```
nullableObject.ifPresent(obj -> {
    if (!"A".equals(obj.getStatus())) {
        throw new BusinessUncheckedException("exception message");
    }
});
```

**Note:** As @Pshemo mentioned in the comments, the contract of the `Consumer` functional interface allows throwing only RuntimeExceptions.

Otherwise, you are better off with a *if* check as you've mentioned.

IMO, using a `filter` on Optional for checks like these is not that readable/intuitive. I would prefer,

```
if (obj != null && !"A".equals(obj.getStatus())) {     
    throw new BusinessUncheckedException("exception message");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `map` to null, the Optional becomes empty:

```
Optional.ofNullable(nullableObject)
    .map(object -> "A".equals(object.getStatus()) ? object : null)
    .ifPresent(object -> { throw new BusinessUncheckedException("exception message"); });
```

Comment: I don't tested but I think it will throws an NullPointerException when the object is null. (object.getStatus...)

Comment: @VictorSoares `object` is never null.

Comment: Ok you are right. But it will throws the BusinessUncheckedException anyway

Comment: The OP doesn't want to throw the exception if `nullableObject` is *null*. The rule is, it could be null - or if not null, then it's getStatus must be `A`.